# displaying data after ajax call in Ember

Tags: ember.js

One of the founders of Discourse has posted an entry on his blog http://eviltrout.com/2013/02/27/adding-to-discourse-part-1.html explaining how he makes ajax queries in Ember (as opposed to using Ember data). If the user navigates to a route it will trigger a found method

Route

```
   Discourse.AdminReportsRoute = Discourse.Route.extend({
     model: function(params) {
        return(Discourse.Report.find(params.type));
      },
```

Find method

```
Discourse.Report.reopenClass({
  find: function(type) {
    var model = Discourse.Report.create();
    jQuery.ajax("/admin/reports/" + type, {
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(json) {
        model.mergeAttributes(json.report);
        model.set('loaded', true);
      },
    });
    return(model);
  }
});
```

I got this to work using a different example, however, in the success callback I get this error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mergeAttributes'
```

As I didn't have Discourse set up, I created a different domain model

```
App.Restaurant = Ember.Object.extend({});

App.Restaurant.reopenClass({
  find: function(type) {
    var model = App.Restaurant.create();
    jQuery.ajax("restaurants/",{
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        model.mergeAttributes(json.restaurants);
        model.set('loaded', true);
      },
    });
    return(model);
  }
});
```

Logging the json in the success callback showed this

```
Object {restaurants: Array[28]}
restaurants: Array[28]
__proto__: Object
```

Why isn't mergeAttributes defined on my model?

I tried to remove model.mergeAttributes and just do

```
 success: function(json) {    
        model.set('loaded', true);
      },
```

I get this error

```
Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed <App.Restaurant:ember322>
```

So if I can't do mergeAttributes, is there a way to make the data returned in the success callback an array?

```
{{#if loaded}}
<ul>
   {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>

    {{else}}
  {{ loading}}
{{/if}}
```

--

```
  model: function(params) {
    return(App.Restaurant.findAll(params));

  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('restaurants', {into: 'application'});
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems:

First, `mergeAttributes` is not built into Ember. It is something Discourse defines in `Discourse.Model` which is the model base class they use. The definition is here: https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/models/model.js#L12-L38

The second issue is that in your `App.Restaurant.find` call you are fetching a list of restaurants but then creating a single model and returning it. Consequently, the object passed to the `each` helper is just a single `App.Restaurant` object instead of an array. This is what the `Assertion failed` error you pasted is referring to.

To accomplish what you want, you should probably do something like the following:

```
App.Restaurant.reopenClass({
  findAll: function() {
    jQuery.getJSON("restaurants").then(function(json) {
      return json.restaurants.map(function(attrs) {
        return App.Restaurant.create(attrs);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. According to the console, the ajax is working now (and i learned something:) however it's not rendering into the template the way that I'm calling the method (see bottom of OP for how I'm calling it and trying to render it). If you can add a bit more detail I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possibly not rendering because the callback isn't setting `loaded` on the model array being returned. As an aside, that pattern (returning a model right away and using loaded flags to check whether to render) isn't as common in Ember these days. The reason is that in recent versions of the router, if a `model` hook returns a promise, the transition will pause until the promise resolves. As a result, the template won't render until the model data is available so the guard is unnecessary. Anyway, I'm just guessing here. If this doesn't work, post a jsbin and I will comment further.

Comment: I removed the check for `loaded` from templates and it's still not working. Here's a jsbin showing what I'm doing although I'm not sure how to make it work without server data http://jsbin.com/EvOmEfe/5/edit  Maybe you can still see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Things to note: I've added a simulated JSON response instead of the `$.getJSON` call. I've updated both Ember and Handlebars to 1.0.0. There are a number of features you are using that have changed since rc6 (what you had originally) so unless there is a good reason to stay on the older version I recommend updating to avoid having to change some of your code. I added an 'about' route and router entry so that the `link-to` you have works. Finally rendering `{{item}}` renders stuff like `<App.Restaurant:ember269>` so you probably want to render a specific attribute like `{{item.name}}`.